# How to create a frequency table?

Tags: frequency, percentage

I am supposed to create a frequency table to describe the data using 4 measures:

- Raw frequency
- Cumulative raw frequency
- Relative frequency
- Cumulative percentage

I don't understand what these mean, if someone could please explain them I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table of counts generated as follows:

```
category num
       a  10
       b   5
       c  15
       d  20
```

The variable `num` is the raw frequency. The relative frequency is the percentage of the sample with a particular `category` label. The cumulative measures only make sense if the `category` is an ordered term. Cumulative raw frequency is the cumulative counts. Cumulative relative frequency is the cumulative percentage.

We would expand the table in the following way:

```
category rawfreq relfreq cumrawfreq cumrelfreq
       a      10      .2         10         .2
       b       5      .1         15         .3
       c      15      .3         30         .6
       d      20      .4         50        1.0
```

Comment: Thanks!
Hey I ended up completing my graph. Have it all set up now. How would you describe the distribution? and does it make sense to include the last category? Here is a link to my question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327792/how-does-one-describe-the-distrubtion-of-this-graph-does-it-make-sense-to-inclu